# Google Maps Places API Map not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I just started working with the google maps places API and have been able to pull together this code but the map doesn't show up.  I would imagine it is a small error somewhere but I can't find it.  If anyone could point it out that would be a huge help and also is there anywhere online or any free IDEs that are good for catching errors like this?

Code: http://jsbin.com/ifuwel/1/edit

Comment: try to show a basic map, and work your way up with slight changes you can track back. also, you should get firefox and firebug extension to see the console.

Comment: Yeah that's actually exactly what I did.  I had the basic map working and have gotten a lot of other options and then this one stumped me for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different IDs ("map" and "map_canvas"). Try that:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this basic example

HTML

```
 <body onload="initialize()">
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 </body>
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                  mapOptions);
  }
</script>
```

CSS

```
    <style>
     html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
      }

     #map_canvas {
     height: 100%;
     }

     @media print {
     html, body {
     height: auto;
     }

     #map_canvas {
     height: 650px;
     }
      }
    </style>
```

CSS help to have 100% of the width and height if desired